# How to change value on PHP?

Tags: php, combobox

I am new to PHP, I would like to build a PHP page that include a combobox and a submit button. The combobox allow us to select the value of month, Jan,Feb... and so on.
By default, the value on PHP is: `$value="Jan"`, if I select the combobox from Jan to Mar, the value on PHP should change to `$value="Mar"`.
So, how can I achieve such a functionality?

Comment: Try the code. Syntax can be googled. Get the last value from the selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code .

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo $mont = $_POST['month'];

}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name='month'>
        <?php
        $monts = array('jan', 'fab','march','april', 'may', 'june', 'july','aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec');
        foreach ($monts as $value) {?>
           <option value="<?php echo $value?>" <?php if($mont == $value ) { echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php echo $value; ?></option><?php }
         ?>
     </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name='submit'></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select multiple values from the combobox and submit the form, in the PHP you will get an array of selected values. So you can get the last value only from that array.

```
$combo = $_POST['combo'];// array(0=>"Jan", 1=>"Feb",2=>"Mar");
$value = $combo[count($combo)-1]; //Mar
```

Comment: i think it should be `count - 1` right? Because it's starting with 0 :)

Comment: @Refilon: Yes, Right..Thanks Man :)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://webplums.com/temp/demo_23465792/#)

**common.php**

```
<?php
$ArrayList = array(1=>'Ford',2=>'Chevy');

$ArraySubList[1] = array(1=>'Focus',2=>'Explorer');
$ArraySubList[2] = array(1=>'Cavalier',2=>'Impala', 3=>'Malibu');
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   
    return null;
}

function ajax_function(url, postData, id)
{
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                            
        }       
    }                
        xmlhttp.send(postData);
}

function dispSecond(Id)
{
    var params  = 'Id=' + Id ;
    var DivId = 'dispDiv';
    ajax_function('ajax_display.php', params, DivId);
}

</script>

<?php
require_once('common.php');
?>

<select id="drop_first" name="drop_first" onchange="return dispSecond(this.value);">
<option value="0">[Select]</option>
<?php
foreach ($ArrayList as $k=>$v)
{
echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';  
}
?>
</select>

<div id="dispDiv"></div>
```

**ajax_display.php**

```
<?php
require_once('common.php');

$Id     = isset($_REQUEST['Id']) ? $_REQUEST['Id'] : '';
if ($Id)
{
$SubArray = $ArraySubList[$Id];
?>
    <select id="drop_second" name="drop_second">
    <option value="0">[Select]</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($SubArray as $k=>$v)
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';  
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Note:**
common.php, change the array values or retrieve from mysql